# What is the result of the join of two rdd?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

The element in clickRdd is `(h5id,[query])`, where h5id is a long number and query is a string; the element in revealRdd is `(h5id, [0:id, 1:query, 2:q0, 3:q1, 4:q2, 5:q3, 6:s0, 7:s1, 8:s2, 9:s3] ).`
and what is the result of  `clickJoin = clickRdd.join(revealRdd)`, I guess the join key is h5id. 
Anyone can give me the content after joining ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joined RDD will have both the values of rdd in a tuple and hi5id as key.

```
clickJoin.take(1)
[(hi5id,([query],[0:id, 1:query, 2:q0, 3:q1, 4:q2, 5:q3, 6:s0, 7:s1, 8:s2, 9:s3]))]
```